# Hydrate not called

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I am trying to hash a value received from the client side, to compare it with the hashed value matching a username.

Here is the call:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/user/?format=json&name__exact=jean&nickname__exact=mynickname
```

Here is my resource:

```
class MUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        filtering = {
            'name': ['exact'],
            'nickname': ['exact'],
        }

    def dehydrate_nickname(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['nickname'] = hashlib.sha1(bundle.data['nickname']).hexdigest()
        return bundle.data['nickname']
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `dehydrate_foo` and not `hydrate_foo`. Hydrate is used for when you de-serialize your incoming data.

Comment: Using dehydrate works, but gave me a Bus error : 10 when trying to call this url now.

Comment: You shouldn't get that. Something might be screwy with your install. Are you on OSX?

Comment: Yes it is ok now. Stupid mistake on my side. My question is the following in fact, I guess I misunderstood hydrate/dehydrate.
Let's say I sent a plain password on the network (for the sake of example), by requestion my API. On the server side, before going to check in my model, I wanna hash the plain value that I received. So let's say, I redceive test as a field, and I need to hash it to check if it exists because my database contains hashed values. Isn't it supposed to be using hydrate?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you need to POST it. The example above is a GET request.

Comment: Yes I figured that out. In my case I would ne build_filters. Thank you for your answer though